# Highcharts: Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have 2 doubts in following graph:

[image]

First: my x axis is skipping one label

Second: I want my Feb data bar to start from Feb15 (and so on for all the months), as you can see it is starting from Jan15 currently.

Following is my code:

```
chartType.strikeRateFrquency=function(chartObject){
        return{
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar',
                    renderTo: chartObject.element,
                    inverted:false,
                    //rotation:'180',
                    width:550
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                credits:{
                    enabled:false
                },
                xAxis: [
                    {
                        tickInterval : 1,
                        gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                        lineColor:'transparent',
                        tickColor:'transparent',
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                var value = chartObject.cumalative[this.value] ;
                                //console.log(value);
                                return value !== 'undefined' ? value : this.value ;
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            align:'high',
                            text: 'Cumalative'+'<br>'+ 'Score S/R',
                            rotation:0,
                            x:-10,
                            y:-20
                           },
                     },

                    {
                        tickInterval : 1,
                        gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                        lineColor:'transparent',
                        tickColor:'transparent',
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                var value = chartObject.monthsx[this.value];
                                //console.log(value);
                                return value !== 'undefined' ? value : this.value;
                            }
                        },

                    }
                    ],
                yAxis: [{
                    //reversed:true,
                    opposite:true,
                    max:72,
                    min:0,
                    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                    tickInterval: 12,
                    title:{
                        text:''
                    },
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            var value = chartObject.monthsy[this.value];
                            return value !== 'undefined' ? value : this.value;
                        }
                    },

                }],

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal',

                    }
                },
                legend:{
                    enabled:false
                },
                series: [{
                    xAxis:1,
                    name: 'Quarter 2',
                    data: [35, 15, 35, 11, 2,10],
                }, {
                     name: 'Quarter 1',
                    data: [25,15,20,10,15,22],
                }]
        }
}
```

Directive code:

```
function strikeRateFrequency($rootScope, chartTypesFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: {
            graphData: '='
        },
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('graphData', function () {    
                var chartoptions = {};
                chartoptions.element = element[0];
                chartoptions.monthsy={               
                0: 'Jan15',
                12: 'Feb15',
                24: 'Mar15',
                36: 'Apr15',
                48: 'May15',
                60: 'Jun15'}

                chartoptions.monthsx={                
                0: 'Jan15',
                1: 'Feb15',
                2: 'Mar15',
                3: 'Apr15',
                4: 'May15',
                5: 'Jun15'}

                chartoptions.cumalative=['10%','30%','40%','25%','60%','43%'];
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartTypesFactory.strikeRateFrquency(chartoptions));
            });


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish. Why do you have months on both your x and y axes?  Why do yo have a second x axis? If you want to start the bars at different points, you'll have to use a **columnrange** series type, and set **inverted: true** in the chart properties.  But other than that, your data/axis setup doesn't really make sense to offer any additional advice.

Comment: I have some data value(suppose 300) that comes in Jan15, now I want to show the changes in this value due course of time in Jan15, Feb15, Mar15 and so on...do you think gantt chart will solve this?

Comment: That sounds like data that should be plotted as a **line** to me, when you describe it like that. But looking at your original description again, perhaps a **waterfall** chart would do what you want?  Demo here:  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/waterfall